# selenium python How can I find all ID elements that begin the same

Tags: python, selenium

How can I assign all elements that begin with the same id part to a list? I have elements ids that are `'card0'`, `'card1'`, `'card2'` and I want to put all of them in a list. I have tried

```
cards = []
cards = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "card")]')
```

I can find the first one by using

```
cards = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "card0")]')
```

Comment: What about `[e.get_attribute("id") for e in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "card")]')]` , cf [`WebElement.get_attribute`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute).

Answer (score 1):

Use stars-with function from xpath as well:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, "card")]
```

And to be more precise, avoid using * if you want to collect similar elements, and replace it with div, input, li etc (whatever you have there)

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS selector instead of Xpath:

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^=card]")
```

(because CSS has "starts with" [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp)).